# Can you use Photoshop brushes in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, brush

Is there a way to download brushes into Adobe Illustrator?

Answer (score 2):

**No. You can not use Photoshop brushes in Illustrator.**

The application core structure is vastly different and Photoshop brushes won't work in Illustrator just as Illustrator brushes won't work in Photoshop.

Photoshop brushes are based on *pixels*. Illustrator brushes are based on *vector paths*. They simply aren't the same.

You can use a variety of different brushes within Illustrator but they must be made for Illustrator. To load a brush in Illustrator simply double-click the Illustrator brush file or choose `Open Brush Library` from the menu on the **Brush Panel** within Illustrator.